# puppet+hiera+rspec - can't enable merge_behaviour feature

Tags: rspec, merge, puppet

i'm trying to test my puppet+hiera modules with rspec but stuck with one thing.
i can't make **:merge_behaviour: deeper** feature working in my test.
here's the example of my test:

```
require 'spec_helper'
def merge_nil(a,b)
    if a.nil?
       return b
    end
    if b.nil?
       return a
    end
    return a.merge(b)
end
describe 'check' do
    path = File.expand_path(File.join(__FILE__, '..', '..', 'fixtures', 'hieradata'))
    shared_examples 'container' do |common, test|
        res = merge_nil(common['site_users'], test['site_users'])
        it do
            should contain_notify('aa').with('message' => res)
        end
    end
    context 'deeper_change' do
        let(:hiera_config) do{
            :backends => ['yaml'],
            :hierarchy => [
                'test',
                'common'],
            :yaml => {
               :datadir => path
            },
            :merge_behavior => deeper
        }
        end
        common = YAML.load_file(File.join(path,'common.yaml'))
        test = YAML.load_file(File.join(path,'test.yaml'))
        it_behaves_like "container", common, test
    end
end
```

hiera files:

### common.yaml:

```
site_users:
  bob:
    uid: 501
    shell: /bin/bash
  ash:
    uid: 502
    shell: /bin/zsh
    group: common
```

### test.yaml:

```
site_users:
  jen:
    uid: 503
    shell: /bin/zsh
    group: deglitch
  bob:
    uid: 1000
    group: deglitch
```

in manifest i just notify site_users

the test doesn't fail, but it should fail. Because i use Hash.merge in ruby code in function merge_nil and ask Hiera to use deep_merge. The results must differ

i tried to require 'deep_merge' gem inside test

tried

```
:merge_behavior => deeper
:merge_behavior => 'deeper'
:merge_behavior => :deeper
```

nothing changes
where am i wrong?

p.s. puppet itself works properly with

```
:merge_behavior: deeper
```

inside hiera.yaml